# How to filter GTE, LTE on Float or Decimal via Django ORM

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter GPS coordinate points (not using Geodjango) on my app. I need to filter a range, but the float values of the GPS coordinates give me this error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup '_lte' for DecimalField or join on the field not permitted.
[03/Feb/2019 14:51:14] "GET /api-v1/location-within/10.0/10.0/10 HTTP/1.1" 500 136144
```

I tried both float and decimal

Any insight? Thanks! :)

Comment: please add your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an additional underscore in your filter. If your field name is `spam`, then it should be `spam__lte=VALUE`. You need two underscores separating the field and the operator.

Comment: Thank you! I had 2 underscores in 3/4 chained filters and missed that one had the extra underscore. Thanks for spotting it! (I thought the error was telling me I only had one underscore)