# Getting Error: Unsupported lookup 'id' for DecimalField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python-3.x, django, orm, django-views

I'm trying to get a DecimalField in Django from the database by using the ORM, so I can populate a field on my form. I'd like to do something like this: `SELECT trainer_price FROM Trainer WHERE id=3)`.

I'm getting this error: `Unsupported lookup 'id' for DecimalField or join on the field not permitted.` and can't figure out why my query is not working.

This is what I've tried:

1. price = Trainer.objects.filter(trainer_price__id=3)
2. price = Trainer.objects.filter(trainer_price__pk=3)
3. I've also referenced this StackOverflow article: [How to filter GTE, LTE on Float or Decimal via Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501670/how-to-filter-gte-lte-on-float-or-decimal-via-django-orm)

But am still getting the error mentioned above.

Here's my full code for my views.py:

```
def train(request):

    trainer_form = Trainer(request.POST)
    price = Trainer.objects.filter(trainer_price__id=3)
    
    context = {'trainer_form':trainer_form, 'price':price}

    return render(request, "register/trainer_form.html", context)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an incorrect Django query.To filter out row where id = 3 and selecting column **trainer_price**, your query should be like this:

```
price = Trainer.objects.filter(id=3).values('trainer_price')
```